# restrict object movement to angle in fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

Is there any way to lock the movement of an object to a specific angle?
e.g i want to move an object along a line with an angle of 45 degrees.

I know about obj.lockMovementX and obj.lockMovementY which can be true or false, what I'm looking for is something like lockMovementTo: degrees - which would only allow the object being moved along a certain angle.

Since I can't answer my own question, this is what I ended up using.
Probably there are more elegant ways to do this - but hey it works :)

```
function restrictMovement(obj, angle){
  if(angle == 270){
    //tan 90 would be a problem
    obj.lockMovementX = true;
    return;
  }
  var start = obj.left;
  obj.on('moving', function(e){
    obj.lockMovementY = true;
    var ar = fabric.util.degreesToRadians(angle);
    //mutiply ar by -1 because we're clockwise..
    var newtop = obj.top  - (obj.left -start)  * Math.tan(ar * -1);
    obj.set('top', newtop);
    start = obj.left;
  });
}
```